# There is no data in ksql table after creating a table on a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm trying to create a ksql table from an existing topic in kafka.
When I query the table no data is showing up.

I tried producing the messages to kafka topic with keys. Those are visible in a ksql stream I created, But when I create a similar table there is no data in the table.

Producing the data:

```
sh kafka-console-producer \
--broker-list kf-pranay-kafka-0.kf-pranay-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 \
--topic ppp \
--property "parse.key=true" \
--property "key.separator=:"
1:{"sr":"1","title":"The Matrix","year":1999,"genres":"Science Fiction"}
2:{"sr":"2","title":"Die Hard","year":1988,"genres":"Action"}
3:{"sr":"3","title":"Toy Story","year":1995,"genres":"Animated"}
```

Creating and querying a stream:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'earliest' to 'earliest'.
ksql>
ksql> CREATE STREAM ppp (sr varchar, title varchar, year bigint, genres varchar) WITH
>(kafka_topic='ppp', value_format='JSON');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql>
ksql> SELECT * FROM ppp;
1560340201759 | 1 | 1 | The Matrix | 1999 | Science Fiction
1560340201767 | 2 | 2 | Die Hard | 1988 | Action
1560340201767 | 3 | 3 | Toy Story | 1995 | Animated
^CQuery terminated
ksql>
ksql> CREATE TABLE movie_table (sr varchar, title varchar, year bigint, genres varchar) WITH
>(kafka_topic='ppp', value_format='JSON', key = 'sr');

 Message
---------------
 Table created
---------------
ksql>
ksql> SELECT * FROM MOVIE_TABLE;
^CQuery terminated
```

I am expecting a similar output from table as SELECT query from a STREAM. But it seems I am not getting any data in the table.

Comment: You're create a different topic, `kafka_topic='movie'` but there is no data there. Everything is still in the `ppp` topic/stream

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, my mistake. Actually I was running the query on same topic "ppp" but I pasted this from my notepad that's why it was kafka_topic='movie'.

Comment: Recommended reading to solve this kind of problem: https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1/